# PHP: Array Search Groups

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I have this script to search a MySQL database, this script shows me how many times one number was extracted from the loto extraction. I don't know how to make it search for number groups like 22,69,80. Any suggestions?

**What this script shows:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wof.png

**Script:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.ro", "******", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*******") or die(mysql_error());

$numere_cautate = false;
if (isset($_POST['numere'])) {
    $search_text = str_replace(" ", "", trim($_POST['numere']));
    if (!empty($search_text)) {
        $numere_cautate = explode(",", $search_text);
    }
}

$search_text = isset($search_text) ? $search_text : "";

$limit = isset($_POST['extrageri']) ? $_POST['extrageri'] : 10;
$limit = is_numeric($limit) ? $limit : 10;

$ultimele_zile = isset($_POST['ultimele_zile']) ? $_POST['ultimele_zile'] : 3;
$ultimele_zile = is_numeric($ultimele_zile) ? $ultimele_zile : 3;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="js/sorttable.js"></script>
    <title>Loto Polonia</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="search">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Numere" name="numere" size="30" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Extrageri" name="extrageri" size="5" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>">
        <select name="ultimele_zile">
            <option value="1">Ultima zi</option>
            <option value="2">Ultimele 2 zile</option>
            <option value="3" selected="selected">Ultimele 3 zile</option>
            <option value="4">Ultimele 4 zile</option>
            <option value="5">Ultimele 5 zile</option>
            <option value="0">Toată baza de date</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Caută">
    </form>    
</div>


<table id="box-table-a" class="sortable" style="float: left; margin: 0 15px 15px 0; text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
            <th scope="col">Aparitii</th>
            <th scope="col">Pauza</th>
            <th scope="col">Pauza max.</th>
            <th scope="col">Media</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if (is_array($numere_cautate)) {
            $cu_limita = ($ultimele_zile == 0) ? "" : "AND data >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $ultimele_zile DAY )";

            foreach ($numere_cautate as $numar_cautat) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$numar_cautat.'</td>';
                echo '<td>';            
                $aparitii = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM extrageri WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$numar_cautat."', numere) > 0 ".$cu_limita." ORDER BY id DESC "));
                echo $aparitii;
                echo '</td>';

                $prima_pauza = false;
                $pauza = $pauza_curenta = $pauza_maxima = 0;            
                $ultimele_extrageri = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM extrageri WHERE id ".$cu_limita." ORDER BY id DESC");
                $numar_ultimele_extrageri = mysql_num_rows($ultimele_extrageri);
                while ($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($ultimele_extrageri)) {
                    $numere = str_replace(" ", "", $rand['numere']);
                    $numere_array = explode(",", $numere);

                    if (!in_array($numar_cautat, $numere_array)) {
                        $pauza++;    
                        if ($pauza > $pauza_maxima) $pauza_maxima = $pauza;    
                    } else {
                        if ($prima_pauza == false) {
                            $pauza_curenta = $pauza;
                            $prima_pauza = true;
                            $pauza = 0;
                        }
                    }            

                    if ($aparitii == 0) $pauza_curenta = $pauza_maxima = $numar_ultimele_extrageri;
                }
                $medie = number_format(($aparitii * 100)/$numar_ultimele_extrageri, 2);
                echo '<td>'.$pauza_curenta.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$pauza_maxima.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$medie.'%</td>';
                echo '</tr>';    
            }
        }
           ?>
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wof.png
This is mysql dump

> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; SET time_zone = "+00:00";
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
>   /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
>
> --
>
> ### -- Bază de date: `loto_polonia`
>
> ---
>
> --
>
> ### -- Structura de tabel pentru tabelul `extrageri`
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extrageri` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `data` date NOT NULL,   `numere` varchar(255) NOT
>   NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;
>
> --
>
> ### -- Salvarea datelor din tabel `extrageri`
>
> INSERT INTO `extrageri` (`id`, `data`, `numere`) VALUES (1,
>   '2014-01-08',
>   '6,9,10,12,14,25,27,30,32,33,34,41,43,50,51,56,59,68,73,74'), (2,
>   '2014-01-08',
>   '6,7,8,11,18,20,24,25,31,45,48,50,51,53,61,67,69,72,75,80'), (3,
>   '2014-01-09',
>   '4,5,6,7,12,19,22,28,32,36,44,48,52,53,57,58,66,74,77,penis'), (4,
>   '2014-01-09',
>   '3,5,6,8,9,13,14,19,26,31,34,41,42,50,54,59,63,67,73,77'), (5,
>   '2014-01-10',
>   '4,5,7,11,15,17,20,22,24,25,31,32,35,41,42,55,60,62,69,75'), (6,
>   '2014-01-10',
>   '1,6,11,12,13,15,19,27,28,31,34,35,40,43,49,51,52,64,66,71'), (7,
>   '2014-01-11',
>   '8,14,21,23,24,28,31,33,39,44,47,48,58,62,64,67,70,71,78,80'), (8,
>   '2014-01-11',
>   '5,8,15,24,31,35,37,39,40,42,47,51,57,58,63,68,70,75,76,78'), (9,
>   '2014-01-12',
>   '1,3,10,11,12,24,31,38,41,48,52,53,56,58,62,64,73,74,75,78'), (10,
>   '2014-01-12',
>   '2,6,9,13,17,21,29,44,50,53,54,56,58,59,65,66,70,71,72,76'), (11,
>   '2014-01-13',
>   '9,10,11,12,15,16,23,26,32,33,34,43,45,49,60,67,69,72,74,78'), (12,
>   '2014-01-13',
>   '4,9,17,18,22,23,25,27,30,31,32,37,44,51,52,55,66,70,71,72'), (13,
>   '2014-01-14',
>   '3,8,16,18,25,26,29,38,41,44,51,54,57,64,66,69,71,76,77,79'), (14,
>   '2014-01-14',
>   '6,7,16,22,24,26,28,35,37,43,46,54,55,58,69,70,71,73,77,79'), (15,
>   '2014-01-15',
>   '4,5,6,10,11,20,23,25,27,28,30,31,37,39,41,53,55,57,70,71'), (16,
>   '2014-01-15',
>   '5,7,10,14,15,19,28,30,36,37,38,45,52,57,58,66,67,72,75,76'), (17,
>   '2014-01-16',
>   '4,6,8,9,10,22,25,34,36,37,40,42,44,47,49,51,58,63,70,73'), (18,
>   '2014-01-16',
>   '7,8,9,10,14,22,23,26,27,29,30,32,48,55,57,58,62,65,67,75'), (19,
>   '2014-01-17',
>   '2,5,8,13,15,22,24,38,41,43,50,56,60,62,64,67,72,74,75,77'), (20,
>   '2014-01-17',
>   '1,6,13,14,19,21,24,25,30,33,38,44,47,49,54,56,57,63,77,80'), (21,
>   '2014-01-18',
>   '2,5,7,10,15,21,26,27,34,36,43,47,50,52,59,68,72,74,76,77'), (22,
>   '2014-01-18',
>   '12,14,17,21,23,27,33,34,35,38,53,57,58,63,64,66,69,70,74,75'), (23,
>   '2014-01-19',
>   '2,4,6,9,17,20,21,30,31,34,36,37,41,49,60,66,67,68,69,78'), (24,
>   '2014-01-19',
>   '1,17,18,25,27,30,32,35,36,37,41,48,55,58,59,64,69,71,72,77'), (25,
>   '2014-01-20',
>   '10,12,14,16,19,20,21,24,29,36,43,46,52,53,55,56,61,63,64,79'), (26,
>   '2014-01-20',
>   '2,6,7,14,20,21,22,26,35,43,44,46,47,50,59,60,63,64,72,76'), (27,
>   '2014-01-21',
>   '7,9,10,11,12,15,18,24,25,39,44,51,54,55,56,57,60,66,74,77'), (28,
>   '2014-01-21',
>   '3,9,14,15,22,30,39,40,50,52,55,56,59,60,68,69,71,75,79,80'), (29,
>   '2014-01-22',
>   '1,15,17,18,19,22,23,25,27,36,39,51,53,54,56,60,61,62,69,74'), (30,
>   '2014-01-22',
>   '2,4,8,16,21,25,27,31,40,45,47,52,54,56,59,62,69,71,73,77');
>
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[PHP-Array\]Group Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377764/php-arraygroup-script)

Answer (score 0):

There may be more options, but one that you can use is like this:

```
select ID from extrageri where ( NUMERE LIKE '%80%' ) and ( NUMERE LIKE '%22%' )
```

Of course you can add more options and combine and/or. Check and example with your data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4f55/11). That query is just an example, you can add ordering, grouping or any other element that you need.

Comment: Use IN() function to search multiple values WHERE id IN('22','80','69').. so you will get the results for above numbers.