# [PHP-Array]Group Script

Tags: php, arrays

Hey stackoverflow comunity i have this script to search a MySQL database, this script shows me how many times one number was extracted from the loto extraction. I don't know how to make it search for number groups like 22,69,80.

**What this script shows:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wof.png

**Script:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect("mysql.hostinger.ro", "******", "*****") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("*******") or die(mysql_error());

$numere_cautate = false;
if (isset($_POST['numere'])) {
    $search_text = str_replace(" ", "", trim($_POST['numere']));
    if (!empty($search_text)) {
        $numere_cautate = explode(",", $search_text);
    }
}

$search_text = isset($search_text) ? $search_text : "";

$limit = isset($_POST['extrageri']) ? $_POST['extrageri'] : 10;
$limit = is_numeric($limit) ? $limit : 10;

$ultimele_zile = isset($_POST['ultimele_zile']) ? $_POST['ultimele_zile'] : 3;
$ultimele_zile = is_numeric($ultimele_zile) ? $ultimele_zile : 3;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="js/sorttable.js"></script>
    <title>Loto Polonia</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="search">
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Numere" name="numere" size="30" value="<?php echo $search_text; ?>">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Extrageri" name="extrageri" size="5" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>">
        <select name="ultimele_zile">
            <option value="1">Ultima zi</option>
            <option value="2">Ultimele 2 zile</option>
            <option value="3" selected="selected">Ultimele 3 zile</option>
            <option value="4">Ultimele 4 zile</option>
            <option value="5">Ultimele 5 zile</option>
            <option value="0">Toată baza de date</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Caută">
    </form>    
</div>


<table id="box-table-a" class="sortable" style="float: left; margin: 0 15px 15px 0; text-align: center;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
            <th scope="col">Aparitii</th>
            <th scope="col">Pauza</th>
            <th scope="col">Pauza max.</th>
            <th scope="col">Media</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        if (is_array($numere_cautate)) {
            $cu_limita = ($ultimele_zile == 0) ? "" : "AND data >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL $ultimele_zile DAY )";

            foreach ($numere_cautate as $numar_cautat) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$numar_cautat.'</td>';
                echo '<td>';            
                $aparitii = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM extrageri WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$numar_cautat."', numere) > 0 ".$cu_limita." ORDER BY id DESC "));
                echo $aparitii;
                echo '</td>';

                $prima_pauza = false;
                $pauza = $pauza_curenta = $pauza_maxima = 0;            
                $ultimele_extrageri = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM extrageri WHERE id ".$cu_limita." ORDER BY id DESC");
                $numar_ultimele_extrageri = mysql_num_rows($ultimele_extrageri);
                while ($rand = mysql_fetch_assoc($ultimele_extrageri)) {
                    $numere = str_replace(" ", "", $rand['numere']);
                    $numere_array = explode(",", $numere);

                    if (!in_array($numar_cautat, $numere_array)) {
                        $pauza++;    
                        if ($pauza > $pauza_maxima) $pauza_maxima = $pauza;    
                    } else {
                        if ($prima_pauza == false) {
                            $pauza_curenta = $pauza;
                            $prima_pauza = true;
                            $pauza = 0;
                        }
                    }            

                    if ($aparitii == 0) $pauza_curenta = $pauza_maxima = $numar_ultimele_extrageri;
                }
                $medie = number_format(($aparitii * 100)/$numar_ultimele_extrageri, 2);
                echo '<td>'.$pauza_curenta.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$pauza_maxima.'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$medie.'%</td>';
                echo '</tr>';    
            }
        }
           ?>
    </tbody>
</body>
</html>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wof.png
This is mysql dump

> SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO"; SET time_zone = "+00:00";
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
>   /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
>
> --
>
> ### -- Bază de date: `loto_polonia`
>
> ---
>
> --
>
> ### -- Structura de tabel pentru tabelul `extrageri`
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extrageri` (   `id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `data` date NOT NULL,   `numere` varchar(255) NOT
>   NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;
>
> --
>
> ### -- Salvarea datelor din tabel `extrageri`
>
> INSERT INTO `extrageri` (`id`, `data`, `numere`) VALUES (1,
>   '2014-01-08',
>   '6,9,10,12,14,25,27,30,32,33,34,41,43,50,51,56,59,68,73,74'), (2,
>   '2014-01-08',
>   '6,7,8,11,18,20,24,25,31,45,48,50,51,53,61,67,69,72,75,80'), (3,
>   '2014-01-09',
>   '4,5,6,7,12,19,22,28,32,36,44,48,52,53,57,58,66,74,77,penis'), (4,
>   '2014-01-09',
>   '3,5,6,8,9,13,14,19,26,31,34,41,42,50,54,59,63,67,73,77'), (5,
>   '2014-01-10',
>   '4,5,7,11,15,17,20,22,24,25,31,32,35,41,42,55,60,62,69,75'), (6,
>   '2014-01-10',
>   '1,6,11,12,13,15,19,27,28,31,34,35,40,43,49,51,52,64,66,71'), (7,
>   '2014-01-11',
>   '8,14,21,23,24,28,31,33,39,44,47,48,58,62,64,67,70,71,78,80'), (8,
>   '2014-01-11',
>   '5,8,15,24,31,35,37,39,40,42,47,51,57,58,63,68,70,75,76,78'), (9,
>   '2014-01-12',
>   '1,3,10,11,12,24,31,38,41,48,52,53,56,58,62,64,73,74,75,78'), (10,
>   '2014-01-12',
>   '2,6,9,13,17,21,29,44,50,53,54,56,58,59,65,66,70,71,72,76'), (11,
>   '2014-01-13',
>   '9,10,11,12,15,16,23,26,32,33,34,43,45,49,60,67,69,72,74,78'), (12,
>   '2014-01-13',
>   '4,9,17,18,22,23,25,27,30,31,32,37,44,51,52,55,66,70,71,72'), (13,
>   '2014-01-14',
>   '3,8,16,18,25,26,29,38,41,44,51,54,57,64,66,69,71,76,77,79'), (14,
>   '2014-01-14',
>   '6,7,16,22,24,26,28,35,37,43,46,54,55,58,69,70,71,73,77,79'), (15,
>   '2014-01-15',
>   '4,5,6,10,11,20,23,25,27,28,30,31,37,39,41,53,55,57,70,71'), (16,
>   '2014-01-15',
>   '5,7,10,14,15,19,28,30,36,37,38,45,52,57,58,66,67,72,75,76'), (17,
>   '2014-01-16',
>   '4,6,8,9,10,22,25,34,36,37,40,42,44,47,49,51,58,63,70,73'), (18,
>   '2014-01-16',
>   '7,8,9,10,14,22,23,26,27,29,30,32,48,55,57,58,62,65,67,75'), (19,
>   '2014-01-17',
>   '2,5,8,13,15,22,24,38,41,43,50,56,60,62,64,67,72,74,75,77'), (20,
>   '2014-01-17',
>   '1,6,13,14,19,21,24,25,30,33,38,44,47,49,54,56,57,63,77,80'), (21,
>   '2014-01-18',
>   '2,5,7,10,15,21,26,27,34,36,43,47,50,52,59,68,72,74,76,77'), (22,
>   '2014-01-18',
>   '12,14,17,21,23,27,33,34,35,38,53,57,58,63,64,66,69,70,74,75'), (23,
>   '2014-01-19',
>   '2,4,6,9,17,20,21,30,31,34,36,37,41,49,60,66,67,68,69,78'), (24,
>   '2014-01-19',
>   '1,17,18,25,27,30,32,35,36,37,41,48,55,58,59,64,69,71,72,77'), (25,
>   '2014-01-20',
>   '10,12,14,16,19,20,21,24,29,36,43,46,52,53,55,56,61,63,64,79'), (26,
>   '2014-01-20',
>   '2,6,7,14,20,21,22,26,35,43,44,46,47,50,59,60,63,64,72,76'), (27,
>   '2014-01-21',
>   '7,9,10,11,12,15,18,24,25,39,44,51,54,55,56,57,60,66,74,77'), (28,
>   '2014-01-21',
>   '3,9,14,15,22,30,39,40,50,52,55,56,59,60,68,69,71,75,79,80'), (29,
>   '2014-01-22',
>   '1,15,17,18,19,22,23,25,27,36,39,51,53,54,56,60,61,62,69,74'), (30,
>   '2014-01-22',
>   '2,4,8,16,21,25,27,31,40,45,47,52,54,56,59,62,69,71,73,77');
>
> /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
>   /*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
>   /*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

Comment: Demo:http://lotopolonia.besaba.com/

Comment: Y U no code in english?

Comment: in romanian i will write you some LEGENDS Legends:

numere=numbers
numar=number
pauza_curenta=How many times this number is not selected form the last time
pauza_maxima=How much is the max. times for this number is not selected
apariti=How many times this number has been selected
ultimele_zile=past days
numar_cautat=searching number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the IN clause in MySQL. This is a better solution compared to: "X OR Y OR Z";

An example with the IN clause:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (22, 69, 80);
```

This will return the record where ID is equal to one of the set you have given.
Read more: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

At the presentation layer you can apply a SELECT with the multiple attribute. The user can select multiple items from a list using CTRL. Here you can see an example: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Although this presentation method requires you to load all records from the database, you can also use AJAX to find the records you want and get their IDs. For example: http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/